# When can we safely treat $dx$ like it were a real number during integration by substitution

Tags: riemann-integration, formal-proofs

$\def\R{\mathbf{R}}$
**Disclaimer.** I am aware that this is similar to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21199/is-frac-textrmdy-textrmdx-not-a-ratio), but the difference here is I'm asking, *when can we safely treat these 'infinitesimal' quantities as though they were real numbers to solve problems quickly.*

Learning analysis has taught me to attempt most calculus problems as carefully (i.e. rigorously) as possible. But even "simple" problems become tedious very quickly. Say we want to show that $\int_{1}^{x}{\frac{dt}{1+t^2}}$ = $-\int_{1}^{1/x}{\frac{dt}{1+t^2}}$ for all $x\in\R$, (with the understanding that for $x=0$ the right side's limits become $\int_{1}^{\infty}$).
Doing this non-rigorously would be fairly quick:

---

*Non rigorous proof.*
Let $u=1/t$. Then we have $du=-dt/t^2=-dt\cdot u^2$. The limits $t=1$ to $t=x$ changes to become $u=1$ to $u=1/x$. Substituting this in the LHS, we get
$$\tag{1}\int_{t=1}^{t=x}{\frac{dt}{1+t^2}} = \int_{u=1}^{u=1/x}{\frac{-du/u^2}{1+1/u^2}}=\int_{u=1}^{u=1/x}{\frac{-du}{u^2+1}}=-\int_{t=1}^{t=1/x}{\frac{dt}{1+t^2}}$$
Which proves the claim. $\square$

---

I do not understand what an equation like $du=-dt/t^2$ "exactly" means, nor do I think I need to. I believe that it's a very clever notational trick that allows us to "get the answer" without worrying about the technical details. However, I wanted to understand when we can rely on these "18th century" style arguments so we don't have to give formal arguments every time like the one below:

---

*Proof.* Define $f:\R\to\R$ to be $f(t):=\frac{1}{1+t^2}$ and the reciprocal function $g:\R\setminus\{0\}\to\R$ via $g(t)=1/t$. Then $f$ and $g$ are continuously differentiable (proofs omitted) and hence integrable. Now we can compose these functions $f\circ g:\R\setminus\{0\}\to\R$, (which is still continuous), and now see that $f=-f\circ g \cdot g'$ on  $\R\setminus\{0\}$. Now, for $x>0$, we can write and use the integration by substituting rule since $g$ has continuous derivative and get
$$\tag{2} \int_{1}^{x}{f}=\int_{1}^{x}{-f\circ g\cdot g'}=\int_{g(1)}^{g(x)}{-f}=-\int_{1}^{1/x}{f}.$$
Now for $x=0$, we need to show
$$\tag{3} \int_{1}^{0}{f} =-\int_{1}^{\infty}{f}\stackrel{\text{def}}= -\lim_{x\to\infty}{\int_{1}^{x}{f}}\stackrel{\text{?}}=-\lim_{\substack{x\to0\\x\in(0,\infty)}}{\int_{1}^{1/x}{f}}$$
To do this we define yet another function $F:\R\to\R$ such that $F(x):= \int_{1}^{x}{f}$. By the FTC we have $F$ is continuous. Reiterating the above work we have done in terms of $F$, we can say that $F= -F\circ g$ for $x>0$. Hence we have
$$ \tag{4}\int_{1}^{0}{f}=F(0)=\lim_{\substack{x\to0\\x\in\R}}{F(x)} = \lim_{\substack{x\to0\\x\in(0,\infty)}}{F(x)} =-\lim_{\substack{x\to0\\x\in(0,\infty)}}{F\circ g(x)}=-\lim_{\substack{x\to0\\x\in(0,\infty)}}{\int_{1}^{1/x}{f}}.$$
I'm just going to skip doing the case for $x<0$ because I've spent the last 3 hours(!) writing this $\square$.

I also don't know how to prove the last equality in eq. $(3)$, but it isn't relevant to my main question, but I hope this illustrates my difficulty in proving everything as rigorously as possible.

---

**Hence I ask, when can I sidestep all of the above rigor and safely do the $du = -dt/t^2$ equation gymnastics, treating these quantities like they're numbers and re-arranging them and substituting them with impunity?**

Answer (score 2):

The formal statement of the Theorem "Integration by Subsitution" states, that for $I\subset \mathbb{R}, f:I\to \mathbb{R} \text{ continuous}, \phi :[a,b]\subset \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \text{ 
 differentiable, and } \phi([a,b])\subset I$,
$\int\limits_{a}^bf(\phi(x))\phi'(x)\text{dx}=\int\limits_{\phi(a)}^{\phi(b)}f(u)\text{du}$

Notice, that this is equivalent to substituting $u=\phi(x)$, and replacing $\phi'(x)\text{dx}$ with du. Therefore you can just treat dx and du like variables by substituting them for your Integral.

Hope this helped.

PS: For (3), substitute $x=\frac{1}{x}$